# Gdal:Increase dimensions (Resolution) of image obtained after using createcopy()

Tags: visual-c++, gis, gdal

I am using visual c++ gdal to read .gis file from my desktop and then output the image of that file (png/jpeg). The code accepts the "input.gis" file and then creates "output.png".
Here is my working code :

```
GDALDriver *poDriver;
GDALDataset  *poDataset;
char **papszMetadata;
double adfGeoTransform[6];
int nBlockXSize, nBlockYSize;
int bGotMin, bGotMax;
double adfMinMax[2];
GDALAllRegister();
poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen("C:\\input.gis", GA_ReadOnly );
if( poDataset == NULL )
{
    MessageBox::Show("cannot open");      
}
else
{   
    poDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ); 
    GDALRasterBand  *poBand;
    poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand( 1 );
    float *pafScanline;
    int   nXSize = poBand->GetXSize();

    poBand->GetBlockSize( &nBlockXSize, &nBlockYSize );
    adfMinMax[0] = poBand->GetMinimum( &bGotMin );
    adfMinMax[1] = poBand->GetMaximum( &bGotMax );
    if( ! (bGotMin && bGotMax) )
        GDALComputeRasterMinMax((GDALRasterBandH)poBand, TRUE, adfMinMax);
    poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("PNG");
    if( poDriver == NULL )
        printf("Cannot create image");
    else
    {
        papszMetadata = poDriver->GetMetadata();
        if( CSLFetchBoolean( papszMetadata, GDAL_DCAP_CREATECOPY, FALSE ) )
        {
            printf( "Driver %s supports CreateCopy() method.\n", "png" );
        }
    }
    GDALDataset *poDstDS;
    poDstDS = poDriver->CreateCopy( "C:\\output.png", poDataset, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    if( poDstDS != NULL )
         GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poDstDS );
    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poDataset );
```

}

My problem is when I use createcopy() function from gdal the size of image output is always 99 X 99 (which i guess is the default size). How can I increase the size of image to be outputted for example (512 x 512 )?

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of your output dataset `output.png` are 99 x 99 because those are also the dimensions of your input dataset `input.gis`. To create a new dataset with different dimensions you need to use the `Create` method as described in the [GDAL tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).

The PNG driver unfortunately does not support this method which leaves you with two options:

1. Choose a different output format which supports the `Create` method.
2. Use the `Create` method to create a dataset in your memory and then use `CreateCopy` on it - as suggestested in [this GIS.SE post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/133643/39299)

Comment: I wrote this code . Could you please check it?  Now I getting some weird output. There are lot of scattered dots which is not the expected output. Here is my code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed8zc1mso69i307/Code.txt?dl=0

Comment: I cannot comment on your particular code since I don't speak C++, just on the general GDAL principles.

Comment: Can you please explain me Rasterio function (GF_Read/GF_Write) in general terms? I am finding difficult to understand the parameters in that. I tried reading http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html too. Could you please elaborate? Thanks in advance!